# Convert a string which has JSON into list and then add that list into JSON back

Tags: java, android, json

Here, I have a `String` which has `JSONObject` inside it like this :

```
String a = "{"company_name":"ABC","company_address":"hgfh"}";
```

I added this `JSONObject` into `String` with this code :

```
JSONObject company_one1 = new JSONObject();
                company_one1.put("company_name", cmpy_name.getText()
                        .toString().trim());
                company_one1.put("company_address", cmpy_addrs.getText()
                        .toString().trim());
a = company_one1.toString();
```

But now I've only the `String` and I need to add the `JSONObject` of this `String` a into an `ArrayList` and then convert that `ArrayList` into `JSON` which should look like :

```
  {"id":"5","data":[{"company_name":"ABC","company_address":"hgfh","image":["cmFodWxtaXNocmE="]}]}
```

I have tried lots of things to change format like this, but I'm not getting exact format. Sometimes it adds backslashes `\` itself into `JSON` beacuse we can't create a `JSON` which is already a `JSON`.

Please give me a proper solution for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use gson, jackson or something like that. manually operation for json is horrible.

Comment: Do you know a proper answer? Because I've never worked with gson or jackson.

Comment: i've used jackson for this and loved it.  It has lots of options and works really well.  You can just model a class the way you want it... ie, a field that is a list of strings (or objects better) and then jackson can convert that/those objects to and from JSON

Comment: Just read the documentation for Jackson.  It will walk you through it.

Comment: Can you please change it ??

Comment: I posted a answer with simple example. hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
JSONArray imageArray = new JSONArray();
imageArray.put("cmFodWxtaXNocmE=");
//* you can add more to the image array by using the put method

JSONObject company_one1 = new JSONObject();
company_one1.put("company_name", cmpy_name.getText()
         .toString().trim());
company_one1.put("company_address", cmpy_addrs.getText()
         .toString().trim());

//* add the image array
company_one1.put("image", imageArray);

//* create a JSONArray for company types,
JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray();
dataArray.put(company_one1);
//* you can add more to the array here by using the put method

//* now put all in one main JSONObject
JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObect();
mainObj.put("id", "5");
mainObj.put("data", dataArray);

String finalJsonString = mainObj.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are handling with JSON in a right wary. Maybe you should do like this:

```
        try {
        Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map1.put("company_name", "company_name");
        map1.put("company_address", "company_address");
        Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map2.put("company_name", "company_name");
        map2.put("company_address", "company_address");
        Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map3.put("company_name", "company_name");
        map3.put("company_address", "company_address");
        List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        list.add(map1);
        list.add(map2);
        list.add(map3);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(list);
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject1.put("id", "5");
        jsonObject1.put("data", jsonArray);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not putting the values of `company_name` and `company_address`. I just have to do everything using my `String`

Comment: @AnshulTyagi call `jsonObject1.toString()`, you will get what you want.

Comment: I'm storing `jsonObject1.toString()` into my database and then I call this String somewhere else from database.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi, yes, after you get the string you stored in database, you can also convert the string into a JSONobject, can't you? If not, What do you want on earth?

Comment: I can convert but then it adds backslashes \ itself.

Comment: I don't think of it as a problem, only if you can handle with the String in JSON or others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73395/discussion-between-anshul-tyagi-and-silentknight).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/17/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/), if you wish to use GSON as library to serialize and de-serialize json data. Visit Tutorail [Java Object  to/from JSON](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/17/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/)  and library [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudo code.(so it could not be compiled maybe)
But `Gson` is pretty easy and useful.

```
class Company {
  String name;
  ... // constructors, getter/setters...
}

class CompanyGroup {
  int id;
  List<Company> companies;
  ... // constructors, getter/setters...
}

String name = "ABC";
Company a = new Company(name);

int id = 5;
CompanyGroup g = new CompanyGroup(5);
g.companies.add(a);

String r = new Gson().toJson(g);
System.out.println(r);
// I/System.out﹕ {"companies":[{"name":"ABC"}],"id":5}
```